# how to declare method which returns base Class

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, class

I would like to add a method which returns `Class` like below:

```
-(Class) validatorClass{
```

return [AddItemValidator class]; }

and use it like this:

```
self.validator = [[self validatorClass] alloc] initWithParentDirectory:self.parentDirectory];
```

How should I declare the return type `-(Class)` of this method to allow returning only classes which extend from defined class?

I would like to return something like `-(Class<'NameValidator'>)` where `AddItemValidator` extends from `NameValidator`.

How should I declare it?

Comment: You can use 'id' and then typecast to respective class.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this? Prevent compiling if variable of wrong class is specified at left side?

Comment: Can't be done, just look at UIView's +(Class)layerClass method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As SomeGuy mentioned, you can't achieve compile-time safety in this case. Instead, you can use an assertion to have it checked at the runtime (better than nothing):

```
-(Class) validatorClass{
    Class theClass = [AddItemValidator class];
    NSAssert([theClass isSubclassOfClass:[NameValidator class]], @"Has to return subclass of %@", [NameValidator class]);
    return theClass;
}
```

You can even go further and apply Factory pattern here to decouple validator class from the class being validated:

```
@implementation NameValidatorFactory

+(NameValidator*)validatorForObject:(YourObjectType*)validatedObject {
  //choose proper validator depending on your object's type or anything you want
  if([validatedObject isKindOfClass:[YourObjectTypeSuperclass class]]) {
    return [AddItemValidator alloc];
  }
  else {
  // handle other cases 
  }

  }
```

And then create your validator like that:

```
self.validator = [[NameValidatorFactory validatorForObject:self] initWithParentDirectory:self.parentDirectory];
```